# Forking in the p-adic field with valuation

Tags: lo.logic, model-theory

I understand that the p-adic field with valuation has NTP2 and so forking=dividing. Does anyone have any explicit examples or a way of characterizing non-forking types and formulas in the theory of $Q_p$ (with valuation)?

Comment: What are NTP2, forking, and dividing?

Comment: I think NTP2 means: "No formula has the Tree Property of the 2nd kind". Forking and dividing are well-known model theoretic concepts, forking has its own [Wikipedia page](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forking_extension).

Comment: This is correct. In particular $Q_p$ is dp-minimal and distal (so NIP). I'm looking for some explicit examples of types that don't split over a set or model (i.e. invariant types in the p-adic field with valuation)

Comment: Some etiquette on [cross-posting](https://math.stackexchange.com/questions/4688551/forking-in-q-p): (1) Don't post a question simultaneously here and on Math Stackexchange. After posting on MSE, you should wait at least a few days - a week is better - before posting here to give people a chance to see and respond to your question. (2) If you do cross-post, you should include the links to the cross-posted questions *in both questions*. The point is to avoid people duplicating effort on the two sites and to make sure all the responses to your question are easily accessible.

Answer (score 2):

This is more of a long comment than an answer.

A formula forks over a set $C$ if and only if it forks over $\mathrm{dcl}(C)$, which is a model because $\mathrm{pCF} = \mathrm{Th}(\mathbb{Q}_p)$ has definable Skolem functions. So we can restrict our attention to forking over models.

Since $\mathbb{Q}_p$ is NIP, a global type forks over a model if and only if it fails to be invariant over that model. So you can characterize forking as follows: a formula $\varphi(x,b)$ forks over $M$ if and only if it has no global extension which is invariant over $M$.

The above characterization is true in any NIP theory. In the paper [On forking and definability of types in some dp-minimal theories](https://arxiv.org/abs/1407.0222), Simon and Starchenko improved on this by replacing "invariant" by "definable" for certain dp-minimal theories (including the theory of $\mathbb{Q}_p$): a formula $\varphi(x,b)$ forks over $M$ if and only if it has no global $M$-definable extension.

You would probably prefer a more "algebraic" characterization referring to the field structure and valuation of $\mathbb{Q}_p$. But I'm not aware of a place where this has been worked out explicitly.